# How to update just one object from a list of objects in Redux by id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I build an app in React with Redux and in my state I have a list of objects and I want to update one object from that list by unique id.

My object looks like:

```
{
id: '',
title: '',
description: '',
label: '',
}
```

My state:

```
const initialState = {
    compare: dayjs().month(),
    savedEvents: [],
}
```

When I push a new event in that list I use:

```
case 'events/setNewEvent':
            return { ...state, savedEvents: [...state.savedEvents, action.payload] };
```

My problem is that I don't know to write the right code to update just one object by id sent from my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of Array method `map` and `spread operator`

```js
function updateOne(array, obj) {
  return array.map((item) => {
    if (obj.id === item.id) {
    // update whatever you want
    return {...item, title: obj.title };
   } else {
    return item;
   }
 })
}
```

reducer:

```js
case 'events/setNewEvent':
   return { 
    ...state, 
    savedEvents: updateOne(state.savedEvents, action.payload) 
  };
```

Comment: When I find the right object I want to change title, description and label. Probably I will say ```item.title = obj.title;
 item.description = obj.description; 
item.label = obj.label;``` and after that how i should write that return ```{ ... item, ???? }``` ?

Comment: `return {...item, title: obj.title, description: obj.description, label: obj.label };` Will update your existing object as you wish.

Comment: I wrote ```return {...item, ...obj };``` and works thank you very much!